# How to leave React checkbox ticked based on state

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I' trying to leave the tickbox checked only if what is checked matches the setFilters, how do i do this?

```js
// from another component 
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({cnt: ["UK"]})



<input type="checkbox"  id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value={d} />
```

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: `checked` is the boolean attribute you're looking for, not `value`.